# How can I make sure my OS can recognize my modem?

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, modem

My modem is an Actiotec MDC AC'97 Modem v2132D. How can I be sure that it's a software or a hardware one? How can I be sure that it works with/is recognizable by my OS?

I'm using Debian Linux 5.0 with KDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading over at [linmodems.org](http://linmodems.org/). They have a script available over there, [scanModem](http://132.68.73.235/linmodems/index.html#scanmodem), that when run provides information about the chipset on the modem found, as well as possible links to resources that will help you in setting up a driver for your modem.